# Is there a syntax to query As fields that function data?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to query a field name in SQL after using a function?

So for example

```
select datediff(hh, startdate, enddate) as HoursBetween
from tbl
where HoursBetween > 0
```

Comment: You know that more than one RDBMS implement their own version of SQL right?

Comment: I am only familiar with SQL from Microsoft and MySQL. I have not had exposure to other systems. I'll make sure the next time I post something I add additional specifics. thanks.

Comment: Next time add tags for the RDBMS :)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you cannot use `ALIAS` that was created on the same level with the `WHERE` clause because `WHERE` clause is being executed first before the `SELECT` clause. You have two choices,

One, use the expression directly in the `WHERE` clause.

```
select datediff(hh, startdate, enddate) as HoursBetween 
from tbl 
where datediff(hh, startdate, enddate) > 0
```

Two, wrap the statement in a subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    select datediff(hh, startdate, enddate) as HoursBetween 
    from tbl 
) ss
WHERE ss.HoursBetween > 0
```

Here's the `SQL Order of Operation`:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (select datediff(hh, startdate, enddate) as HoursBetween
from tbl) AS I
WHERE HoursBetween > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

On MySQL **HAVING** clause can be used in this case:

```
SELECT datediff(hh, startdate, enddate) AS HoursBetween FROM tbl
HAVING HoursBetween > 0
```

Comment: HoursBetween will not be recognised in the having clause.

Comment: @NLwino: I have just tried equivalent query on MySQL 5.5 (MariaDB) and it worked.

Comment: Ah ok, seems like MySQL allows this, oracle and SQL server do not. Can not remove my downvote though since the answer needs to be edited for that. Add to your answer that it's for MySQL. I still think having shouldn't be used if it's something that's normally in the group by though.